# Way to avoid 2 monitor limit

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have a Geforce GTX 560 Ti (http://www.nvidia.de/object/product-geforce-gtx-560ti-de.html).

It has 3 Monitor Slots, but the Card is only able to screen 2 Monitors at one time.

I've heard about these DVI Splitters but the comments on amazon are just incredibly bad so i dont wanna risk wasting money and time.

I'd like to ask you guys, if there is a WAY to AVOID this stupid limit of only 2 monitors.. especially if you actually can plug in 3. ???????????????

I've heard something about screen mirroring, or something that should work via network.. idk. I cant find anything on google about these methods.

It would be OK if 2 monitors have a different display and the TV just copys one but i can't think there is no solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USB 3.1 to [HDMI](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100161018%20600413992&IsNodeId=1), [Displayport](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100161018%20600413994&IsNodeId=1), [DVI](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100161018%20600413991&IsNodeId=1), or [VGA](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=100161018%20600413993&IsNodeId=1) adapters.

As for your card, the [user manual](http://www.nvidia.com/content/geforce-gtx/GTX_560_User_Guide.pdf) (pg. 10) states: "A single GeForce GTX 560 Ti graphics card can support up to two displays per card in a multi-monitor configuration." (I'm guessing the reason for 3 ports is a combination of available PCB space and creating a selling point based on more natively supported connection types.)

Comment: or does the USB adapter takes his access from the gpu?

Comment: @SoliaK A USB adapter isn't going to be much better than the onboard graphics. It's gets its "juice" mainly from the CPU.

Comment: so i dont need an USB -> X adapter since i have the dvi input on my motherboard right?
any other solutions?

Comment: @SoliaK There's always adding another card. With the arrangement of using both dedicated GPU and onboard graphics, you can't feasibly merge them to get combined power. With another card you'd get both the capability of additional monitors and the potential ability to have SLI, making the combined capability of both cards available to things like games.

Answer (score 0):

The limit is baked into the design of the cards, so it would be a matter of finding cards which handle more outputs or using more cards.

@Ouroborus suggestion about USB to (useable output) is a good one - better then relying on network to output video.

Depending on your motherboard, you may also be able to install more then 1 video card - if you have the software to make use of multiple cards and combine the output, that could work as well.

Comment: does the USB adapter takes his access from the gpu or from the onboard graphiccard? in that case i would also have a dvi input from motherboard

Comment: but i dont think you can play any games on the onboard graphiccard right?